# Call of overloaded is ambiguous

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ambiguity

I have the following **compiler error** : `"call of overloaded ‘reduceColors(ipl_image_wrapper&, ipl_image_wrapper&, int)’ is ambiguous"`

I have a wrapper class for IplImage (DrawingDetection.h):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include "Utils.h"

class ipl_image_wrapper
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< IplImage > ipl_image_ptr_t;

    ipl_image_wrapper() {}
    ipl_image_wrapper( IplImage* img ) : _img( img, ipl_deleter ) {}

    IplImage*       get()       { return _img.get(); }
    const IplImage* get() const { return _img.get(); }

private:

static void ipl_deleter( IplImage* ipl_img )
{
 //some code
}

   ipl_image_ptr_t _img;
};
```

And I have the following functions (Utils.h):

```
#include "DrawingDetection.h"

int calculateHomogeneity(const ipl_image_wrapper &img, Factor & factor);
void reduceColors(const ipl_image_wrapper &img, ipl_image_wrapper &out, int levels);
int calculateCComponentsSize(const ipl_image_wrapper &img, Factor &factor);
```

There is no other declarations of this functions (!). I'm not overloading them.

And source code **with** error (Utils.cpp):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "Utils.h"


int calculateCComponentsSize(const ipl_image_wrapper img, Factor &factor)
{
    // some calculations
}
 void reduceColors(const ipl_image_wrapper &img, ipl_image_wrapper out, int levels)
{
    // some calculations
}
int calculateHomogeneity(const ipl_image_wrapper &img, Factor & factor)
{
    // some calculations
}
void getFactorsOfImage( const ipl_image_wrapper &image, Factor& factor )
{
    ipl_image_wrapper gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize ( image.get() ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    // some calculations
    calculateHomogeneity( gray, factor ); // ok
    reduceColors( gray, gray, 20 ); // ambiguity !!
    int n1 = calculateCComponentsSize( gray, factor );// ambiguity !!
    reduceColors( gray, gray, 8 );// ambiguity !!
    int n2 = calculateCComponentsSize( gray, factor );// ambiguity !!

    // some calculations
}
```

What is the diiference between calculateHomogeneity(...) function and the rest? They have a similar list of parameters. Where the compiler found the ambiguity?

**EDIT:**

Declaration order of function has been very important.

Source code **without** error (Utils.cpp):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "Utils.h"

void getFactorsOfImage( const ipl_image_wrapper &image, Factor& factor )
{
    ipl_image_wrapper gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize ( image.get() ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    // some calculations
    calculateHomogeneity( gray, factor ); // ok
    reduceColors( gray, gray, 20 ); // ambiguity !!
    int n1 = calculateCComponentsSize( gray, factor );// ambiguity !!
    reduceColors( gray, gray, 8 );// ambiguity !!
    int n2 = calculateCComponentsSize( gray, factor );// ambiguity !!

    // some calculations
}
// After getFactorsOfImage function
int calculateCComponentsSize(const ipl_image_wrapper img, Factor &factor)
{
    // some calculations
}
 void reduceColors(const ipl_image_wrapper &img, ipl_image_wrapper out, int levels)
{
    // some calculations
}
int calculateHomogeneity(const ipl_image_wrapper &img, Factor & factor)
{
    // some calculations
}
```

Comment: You have other declarations of those functions that takes other arguments. Please edit your question contain the _complete_ and _unedited_ error messages, there is probably a hint there.

Comment: please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: apart from the declarations, you have *definitions* of the functions. If they are visible at the call site and have different signatures, that would be a possible reaon for the ambiguity.

Comment: The code given (with a few empty placeholders inserted) compiles fine on a variety of compilers at [liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1lLFi6$10). There's something not shown that is causing the problem.

Comment: I' ve edited code. It is a full version.

Comment: to @ fatih_k:  gcc 4.4

Comment: @Ann, your changes don't really add new information. Try commenting out the two troubled prototypes in Utils.h and see what happens.

Comment: you can just try giving another variable as output reference instead of gray and most probably it will compile.

Comment: @fatih_k, I don't think that's the problem, unless she has some special compiler [restrict flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) detecting aliasing between input and output params. The error message given does not seem to indicate this problem.

Comment: @AnnOrlova, if all else fails, try reducing this to a simpler problem. Start a new project that only makes one function call. Add one piece at a time from the real project back in until it breaks. (Alternately, take away pieces from the real project until it works.) Then examine the last change made to determine how it could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The complete error message from the compiler should contain a list of "candidate" functions with the same name that it found, together with their arguments.  Search the code for these different versions and make sure they are not conflicting anymore.

Comment: @AnnOrlova, I reduced the code you provided to the necessary compilable example: http://ideone.com/6gVZmt But it does contain only dummy implementations of the functions in question. Since you declared them in Utils.h, i guess you define them in Utils.cpp. See my last comment - check the definitions for possible signature mismatches. Try not to use `#include`, if forward declarations are sufficient. You have a circular include of utils.h and drawingdetection.h And see my comment to your earlier question regarding the deleter, it should not be placed inside ipl_image_wrapper

Comment: Now you are providing two different code listings for Utils.cpp - please delete one and leave only the one resembling your situation to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually **are** two different `reduceColors` functions: the one that's declared, whose second argument is `ipl_image_wrapper&`, and the one that's defined, whose second argument is `ipl_image_wrapper`. Make them the same.

Comment: That's what I said in the comments - seems she didn't read :(

Comment: @ArneMertz - I wouldn't speculate about who did or didn't do what. It's not relevant to the problem.